# Set up jar libraries to use in online course

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I am having the hardest time setting up IntelliJ 14 so I can use the libraries provided in an online course I am taking [instructions](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/). They provide two jar files

```
stdlib.jar and algs4.jar
```

each of which contains several java classes. There is also a data folder that contains text files called

```
/algs4-data
```

I created a new project and added these jar files into the

```
src
```

folder. Here is what that looks like
[image: project snapshot]

So I went into the Project Structure and added the libraries as shown in this screenshot

[image: project structure]

Now, all of the classes inside of the jar files include a main method which you should be able to call. The problem is that any time I try to run the main method in any of these classes I get an error. For example, typing in the IntelliJ terminal:

```
Guillermos-iMac:src guillermo$ java StdIn
Error: Could not find or load main class StdIn
```

This StdIn.java file is inside sodlib.jar and has a main method with the following

/**
     * Interactive test of basic functionality.
     */

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Type a string: ");
    String s = StdIn.readString();
    System.out.println("Your string was: " + s);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Type an int: ");
    int a = StdIn.readInt();
    System.out.println("Your int was: " + a);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Type a boolean: ");
    boolean b = StdIn.readBoolean();
    System.out.println("Your boolean was: " + b);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Type a double: ");
    double c = StdIn.readDouble();
    System.out.println("Your double was: " + c);
    System.out.println();

}
```

Now, if I right click on the class itself and run it then I get this error popup 
[image: edit configuration]

which when I choose the module then it runs. I want to be able to run the classes from the terminal so I can pass in arguments (mainly the .txt files in the data folder). I have spent hours trying to figure this out to no avail. Please help!